# How to make a custom element component with ionic2?

Tags: angular, components, ionic2, element

I define a login-button component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-button',
  template:
    `<ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button round (click)="openLogin()">
        Login
        <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})

export class LoginButton {

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello LoginButton');
  }
}
```

Register it as provider in `app.module.ts` and then use it in a html file:

```
<ion-content padding>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Fragen
    </ion-title>

    <login-button></login-button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-footer>
```

No error message. The constructor is called, but the template is not filled into the  element. Obviously one step is missing. Which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to register it as a `provider`, register it as under `declarations` and `entryComponents`.

Then the button can be displayed with the `selector` : `<login-button></login-button>` (no need to import explicitly)

Comment: Then on the console of the browser I get: "No provider for LoginButton"

Comment: hmm wait I just checked my code, I have the `LoginButton` declared in both `declarations` and `entryComponents` in the `NgModule`. No import statement on the page of use, just using the selector tag

Comment: Last thing was it. I imported it into the page of use. Put it away and it works. I also put LoginButton into the providers list again, that made the messaage "No provider for LoginButton" go away ;-)

Comment: Hmm weird I can't recall having to do that, working with a beta version of ionic2?

Comment: No. Version 2.1.12.

Comment: That's CLI or applib version I guess, framework rc2 or rc3 then, weird... Ah well, at least it works now xD